# I could not map my vuex actions in a component

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to map my vuex actions (one particularly) but I keep getting the error `Property or method "logout" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.`. Here is my component code:

```
<template>
  <header id="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <router-link to="/">Vue Authenticate</router-link>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
         ...
        <li v-if="authenticated" @click="logout">
          Log Out
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      authenticated: "isAuthenticated",
    }),
  },

  mathods: {
    ...mapActions(["logout"]),
  },
};
</script>
```

and here is my `store/index.js` file:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
import router from "../router/index.js";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({

  actions: {

    logout({commit}) {
      localStorage.removeItem("idToken");
      localStorage.removeItem("userId");
      commit("clearData");

      router.push("/")
    }
  },
});
```

Any idea of where I am missing something? By the way, mapGetters works perfectly fine.
I am using vuex in version 3.4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing "mathods" instead of `methods`:

```
methods: {
   ...mapActions(["logout"]),
},
```